# Flatten a nested hash in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, json, multidimensional-array, flatten

I have a hash in the structure below

```
{
    "Result": [
        {
            "Links": [
                {
                    "UrlTo": "http://www.example.com/",
                    "Visited": 1365128454,
                    "FirstSeen": 1351907446,
                }
            ],
            "Index": 0,
            "Rating": 120.969674
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want it flattened and to look as it does below.
So I want to move the links hash up a level so it is no longer multidimensional. 
What is the easiest way of accomplishing this? can i used something like .flatten?

```
{
    "Result": [
        {
            "UrlTo": "http://www.example.com/",
            "Visited": 1365128454,
            "FirstSeen": 1351907446,
            "Index": 0,
            "Rating": 120.969674
        }
    ]
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: maybe that is a little better?

Comment: I want to move everything that "Links" contains up a level in to the hash above it

Comment: That is what you should have written in the question from the beginning. By the way, is that supposed to be json? If so, shouldn't that be handled by JavaScript or something? Why is Ruby relevant?

Comment: Sorry :/. Because I am trying to map it to a rails model

Comment: Use a combination of Array `flatten`, Hash `assoc`, and Hash[]. In the general case, you'll need a recursive function.

Comment: The code for this will be awful.

Comment: How would you suggest saving this in a db?

Comment: Is possible to have the output of: p your_hash.to_s  ?

Comment: @byterussian it is {
    "Result"=>[{
        "Links"=>[{
            "UrlTo"=>"http://www.example.com/", 
            "Visited"=>1365128454
        }], 
        "Index"=>0, 
        "Rating"=>120.969674
    }]
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = { ... }

h = data['Result'].first
h.merge!(h.delete('Links').first)
```